# Unpaid Leave in non-US Company on F-1 Visa

Tags: usa, student-visa, employment

Is it permissible to have pre-existing employment with a non-US company, then go on unpaid leave, then enter the US and study in the US with an F-1 visa while being on unpaid leave with that non-US company? As far as I know, working for a non-US company is not permissible on an F-1 visa, but in this case no work would be done nor compensation received. Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

The law doesn't forbid being on the rolls as an employee on leave. It forbids working.

That said - for legal advice talk to a licensed attorney.